# Thumbs.db file in res/drawable/hdpi folder

Tags: android

There's this file in my res/drawable-hdpi folder called Thumbs.db and it has an error on it.
I can't compile my project because of this. What exactly does this file do? Should I delete this file? I mean is it safe? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a windows specific file generated when you do a thumb view of an image, nothing to do with Android. You can delete this file

http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Thumbs.db

Comment: To *ignore* see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448042/can-i-hide-thumbs-db-in-android-studio