# Can I hide Thumbs.db in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm working with a libGDX project in Android Studio, that has an assets directory containing photos.

Windows being Windows, it likes to create a Thumbs.db file when I browse through this directory in Windows Explorer. However, Android Studio (1.1.0) displays a Thumbs.db file in the folder directory (Project Window).

Since some applications, like Visual Studio, automatically hide system files, or let you exclude them, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in Android Studio/IntelliJ, or if I just have to live with the file.

My `.gitignore` is already excluding these from being checked into source control; I'm really just looking for a way to hide Thumbs.db from displaying in the listing of a directories files in Android Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can add `Thumbs.db` to the list of ignored files and folders in:

> `File` | `Settings` | `IDE Settings` | `File Types` > `Ignore files and folders`

Comment: Well that was both simple and not where I looked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! In Android Studio 3, the setting is in `File | Settings | Editor | File Types | Ignore files and folders`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the location of "Ignore files and folders" for Android Studio 4.1.1:
[image]